# AWS API Gateway API Key vs Cors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am implementing an API Gateway using AWS.

Do I need to enable CORS on my resources if they require an API key? Does enabling CORS give me an extra layer of security that the API key requirement doesn't?

Or is it the case that needing an API Key to call the API Gateway makes CORS redundant because even if a request from another origin is made - that origin won't have the API key.

Answer (score 1):

First of all CORS and API Key functionality there for different reasons.

API Key - After enabling API Keys each consumer needs to send the API Key with their requests. This is there basically to monitor usage and throttle requests from individual consumers.

CORS - This is basically three to grant modern browsers in directly accessing the API for B2C integrations. If CORS are configured for a particular domain, a website hosted in the  particular domain is only allowed to directly access the API from clientside (Using JavaScript and AJAX). However this might not hold for B2B integrations of the API where even CORS are not configured it is possible to access the API from a backend.

> Is it the case that needing an API Key to call the API Gateway makes CORS redundant because even if a request from another origin is made - that origin won't have the API key.

Yes its true that if API Keys enabled each origin have to have a API Key when accessing the API. However, CORS addresses a different issue where it is a policy enforcement by Web Browsers to limit accessing the API only from whitelisted domains (Otherwise people will be able to send API calls from different web sites to the API simply adding a script and the URL which will overload the API).

Comment: The people sending API calls from different web sites won't have the API key though - will it still overload the API? Is there a difference between being rejected by the API for not having the right API Key and being rejected for failing the CORS validation?

Comment: @Ogen API Keys are validated on server side (on the gw), while CORS headers authorizes the user's web browser to make a cross-site call (the headers are just returned by API gw, not validated, they have nothing to do with API gw security).  API keys are intended gor server-server communication, do not used them from a user's browser (it is easy to collect them)